# How to upload WP user avatar on woocommerce account page

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, avatar

I am using WP User Avatar Plugin instead of gravatar for user profile.

But gravatar is not working so well.
I want to add image upload field on woocommerce account page.

How can I do that?
Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now it’s time to get your hands dirty. Open up your functions.php file located in wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/ and add this code in it:

```
/**
  * Print the customer avatar in My Account page, after the welcome message
  */
 function storefront_myaccount_customer_avatar() {
     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

     echo '<div class="myaccount_avatar">' . get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, 72, '', $current_user->display_name ) . '</div>';
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'storefront_myaccount_customer_avatar', 5 );
```

Then open your style.css file in the same path and add this code:

```
.myaccount_avatar {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    width: 83px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Patel. It helps. But I want to make upload form on account page also. So users can change their avatar more freely. Let me know about this more.